# Flutter Change color Notches

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I have a question.

Is it possible to change the color of the phone notch? how is it framed in red

And detect the oval edge of the screen?
All this in Flutter

[image]

Comment: The notch is not part of the display. Its color is determined in phone manufacture time. Drawing a border however may be possible, apart from the notch I know that it is.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you wish to change the color of the status bar? If so you can add this code snippet in your initState function.

```
  void initState() 
  {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.white,
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, 
    ));
    super.initState();
  }
```

The statusBarColor will be the actual color of the background of your status bar.
The other two attributes change how the icons of the status bar look.

Answer (score 1):

To detect the oval edge and make sure content isn’t on it where you can’t see it, wrap your Scaffold in a SafeArea.